# Get EPSG code or CRS name from Proj4 WKT

Tags: gdal, proj, well-known-text

I am trying to get the EPSG code from a proj4 WKT.

```
:“+proj=lcc +lat_1=46.183333333 +lat_2=47.483333333 +lat_0=45.666666667 +lon_0=-100.5 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=us-ft +no_defs”
```

But I am unable to do so, I tried the same in QGIS but it also says user defined CRS. Although ArcMap is showig the CRS name correctly NAD_1983_StatePlane_Ohio_North_FIPS_3401_Feet. Is there any API or way to get EPSG code from a proj4 wkt.

Answer (score 4):

If you have QGIS installed, you can search its CRS database for `Ohio` to find:

```
EPSG:102722 NAD_1983_StatePlane_Ohio_North_FIPS_3401_Feet
+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.43333333333333 +lat_2=41.7 +lat_0=39.66666666666666 +lon_0=-82.5 +x_0=600000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs
```

As you can see, it uses different standard parallels. Searching for `+lat_1=46.183333333`, you may end up on http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2002-July/000438.html containing

```
# NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Dakota_South_FIPS_3302_Feet
<102721> +proj=lcc +lat_1=46.183333333 +lat_2=47.483333333 +lat_0=45.666666667 +lon_0=-100.500000000 +x_0=600000.000 +y_0=0.000 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096
```

which seems to fit better.

Note that EPSG:102721 is not part of the EPSG registry, but rather invented by ESRI.

EPSG:2266 is basically the same, and part of the official [EPSG registry](https://www.epsg-registry.org/).

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=47.48333333333333 +lat_2=46.18333333333333 +lat_0=45.66666666666666 +lon_0=-100.5 +x_0=599999.9999976 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=ft +no_defs
```

BTW the code in your question is not called WKT, but proj.4 string.

The full WKT definition can be looked up at https://epsg.io/2266 or https://epsg.io/102721

A lookup service for WKT input exists at http://prj2epsg.org/search.